# Wpf ComboBoxColumn selected items to string list

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

question : how i can get a `List<string>` of all selected items in `ComboBoxColumn`so i can change the old values on my DB
im new into wpf and overflow so forgive me if i made any mistake

Comment: Let me know what is the difficulty that you are facing to do this?

Comment: dont know how to do it (any help woud be great)

Comment: http://hpics.li/2fa9454 here is a pic of my prog

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 0 is the index of the ComboBoxColumn.

```
int j = DataGD.Items.Count;
int i = 0;
do
{
DataGridRow row = this.DataGD.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as DataGridRow;
ComboBox ele = this.DataGD.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as ComboBox;
string newS = ele.Text;
list.add(newS);
i++;
} while (i < j);
```